# Unexpected crashes in Vulkan geometry shader

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

I am experiencing odd crashes when doing float comparisons in a Vulkan geometry shader. The shader code is as follows:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip,  max_vertices=3) out;

layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 modelView;
    mat4 staticModelView;
} ubo;

in vec2 texCoordGeom[];

layout(location = 0) out vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    float dist0 = length(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz);
    float dist1 = length(gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz);
    float dist2 = length(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz);

    float maxDist = max(dist0, max(dist1, dist2));

    if(maxDist < 0.01) {
        gl_Position = ubo.modelView * gl_in[0].gl_Position;
        texCoord = texCoordGeom[0];
        EmitVertex();

        gl_Position = ubo.modelView * gl_in[1].gl_Position;
        texCoord = texCoordGeom[1];
        EmitVertex();

        gl_Position = ubo.modelView * gl_in[2].gl_Position;
        texCoord = texCoordGeom[2];
        EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

It appears to crash at the conditional:

```
if(maxDist < 0.01)
```

When I remove this conditional the code runs without issues. If I change the value of the threshold from 0.01 to something larger, such as 0.1 or 1, again the code runs without issues.

Note that I am using the glslangValidator.exe from the VulkanSDK to compile the shader code. No validation errors are thrown except for the warning:

Warning, version 450 is not yet complete; most version-specific features are present, but some are missing.

Also note that no helpful errors are thrown when the program does crash as the entire GPU freezes (screen goes black momentarily) and the program exits.

Comment: If the driver is reset by running into a TDR it's hard to tell what's the cause. My first suspicion was a SPIR-V reflection bug in the driver, but if the shader is actually working if you just change the value you compare against I dont' think that's the case here.
The version warning btw. can be ignored.
One thing I'd change about the shader is to always call EndPrimitive, even if no vertices are generated.
If it still crashes you may want to do a repo case and pass it to the IHV that the code crashes on.

Comment: Also, you asked for GLSL 4.50. That includes both of the extensions you ask for. So... why are you asking for them?

Comment: Modified version (color instead texCoord + removed tran. matrix) of this seem to work for me. So there's **probably** nothing wrong with glslangValidator (1.0.37 SDK) and with the shader code. Try a different driver.

Comment: The error you quote is from GLSL compilation. Are you using some extension to compile them on run-time? Try it without that (it may use outdated compiler).

Comment: I'm not using any extension to compile at run time. I precompile the shaders prior to running the application. @SaschaWillems, I tried calling EndPrimitive regardless of if vertices are generated and that didn't seem to help. Thankfully, since I updated both the Vulkan SDK and the driver to their latest December versions the problem has appeared to resolve itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers this appeared to be a driver issue. Since updating to the latest driver (Radeon Driver Packaging Version
16.50.2011-161219a-309792E) along with the latest LunarG Vulkan SDK (1.0.37.0) the problem has resolved itself. Note I was running on an
AMD Radeon R9 380 Series.